# Having trouble adding objects to the start of an array using an indexSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsindexset

I am downloading message objects from a Parse.com backend. I want to take this array of downloaded messages and insert them at the beginning of my local messages array. I am trying to use the code below:

```
  [receivedMessagesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if(!error){

            NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [objects count]-1);
            NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
            [weakSelf.messages insertObjects:objects atIndexes:indexSet];
            handler(YES, nil,NO,NO);
        }



    }];
```

I am not getting any error messages but for some reason it just isn't adding to the array. Am I creating the range the correct way?

Comment: If `objects` has 1 element, you create a zero-length range. That can't be correct.

Comment: Also verify that `weakSelf.messages` isn't `nil`.

Comment: Note that in the above circumstances, where you must construct an NSIndexedSet object to do it the way shown, it's likely more efficient to just write the obvious loop around `insertObject:atIndex:` (and a lot easier to debug).